# JSON library in Android: Missing InputStream constructor

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to use the Android JSON library, but the version is old and there's no constructor in JSONObject that accepts an InputStream, just a String. I can't read all the contents of the stream to the string because it's longer than the maximum length. Is there a way to add data to the JSONObject after the constructor? If not, how can I upgrade the version in Android?

Comment: It's an API issue, so attaching my code is useless...

Comment: It's not a function for adding string data, it's for adding an element to an array value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not you use, Gson Api, its a third party api by Google. Check following links:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: I ended up using another JSON library, Jackson, but it's much bigger than org.json and for the simple functionality I need (just parsing a Facebook graph API response), I certainly don't need all the packages and classes in there. It's really very annoying I can't just give JSONObject an input stream...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use my open source library: http://code.google.com/p/android-json-rpc/
There is no Input Stream but direct call to JSON REST service.

You can also override the JSONObject class, like this:

```
package com.m4bce.loisirs_ch;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONObjectStream extends JSONObject {

    public JSONObjectStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        super();

        // your code here
    }

}
```

I hope this help.